# Simple SQL Query for date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need a way to find out the number of days for each set of same IDs set. For example, if there are two rows of ID1 with the first date being the 1st and the second date the 4th, the calculation for the 1st would be Sept 4th - the Sept 1st (since the 4th is the next date for ID1) and the calculation for the 4th would be Today (Sept 28th) - Sept 4th (since 4th is the last date for ID1 and there is no more dates after the 4th for ID1). I included the formula for calculation of each column next to it below.

```
IDs    Date          
ID1    09/01/2015    
ID1    09/04/2015  
ID2    09/04/2015    
ID2    09/09/2015   
ID2    09/15/2015  
ID3    09/09/2015 
ID4    09/15/2015
```

To

```
IDs    Date           Days      Formula...
ID1    09/01/2015     3         Sept 4th - Sept 1st
ID1    09/04/2015     22        Today - Sept 4th
ID2    09/04/2015     5         Sept 9th - Sept 4th
ID2    09/09/2015     6         Sept 15th - Sept 9th  
ID2    09/15/2015     13        Today - Sept 15th
ID3    09/09/2015     19        Today - Sept 9th
ID4    09/15/2015     13        Today - Sept 15th
```

Comment: I think your expected output is incorrect. The `ID2` has 3 records. Should the last record for `ID2` be `ID3`?

Comment: I don't think there is anything simple about that, and I'd just pull it and do it in code. This is not the kind of thing SQL was every very good at.

Comment: No ID3 is not the last record for ID2. Each rows has its own set of IDs. @Jonathan Leffler I tried to do this in rdlc report but I couldnt figure it out thats why i though I would just run a query and dump it into a table every time user clicks on the report and get the report from the table.

Comment: @FelixPamittan: They're not in sorted order; when you mentally sort them, that bit of the data is OK.

Comment: Yes @Jonathan Leffler. That is because Sept 15th is the last date for ID2 so the calculation for that is Today - Sept 15th

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically looking for `lead()` functionality.  And, you don't have it, so you have to improvise.  Here is a method using `cross apply`:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(day, t.date, coalesce(n.date, getdate())
from table t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.date
      from table t2
      where t2.id = t.id and t2.date > t.date
      order by t2.date
     ) n;
```

This should have reasonable performance with an index on `(id, date)`.

Comment: Is `LEAD` available on SQL Server 2008?

Comment: @FelixPamittan . . . No.  That why I give the `cross apply` method.

Comment: @FelixPamittan, introduced in 2012, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx

Comment: Haha! you posted this while i had the page open, I have offered a LEAD example answer.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, but it gives me this error: "The multi-part identifier "t2.date" could not be bound."

Comment: I changed the t2.date in line one to n.Date and it worked! is that ok?

Answer (score 2):

Using a common table expression, you can arrange your table into a temporary view with a start date and end date for each ID record, like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/af078/7

```
with t1 (id, dt, ndx) as (
  select id, dt, row_number() over (partition by id order by dt)
  from id_dates
)
,
t2 (id, startdt, enddt) as (
  select t1.id, t1.dt, coalesce(t2.dt, convert(date, getdate()))
  from t1
  left join t1 t2
  on t2.id = t1.id
  and t2.ndx = t1.ndx + 1
)
select * from t2
```

Make sure to use the `coalesce` function to get the current date for the last row (it would otherwise be null from the left join).

From there, it's a simple matter of using the `datediff()` function: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/af078/8

```
with t1 (id, dt, ndx) as (
  select id, dt, row_number() over (partition by id order by dt)
  from id_dates
)
,
t2 (id, startdt, enddt) as (
  select t1.id, t1.dt, coalesce(t2.dt, convert(date, getdate()))
  from t1
  left join t1 t2
  on t2.id = t1.id
  and t2.ndx = t1.ndx + 1
)
select id, startdt, datediff(day, startdt, enddt) as dtcount
from t2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `ROW_NUMBER` together with `LEFT JOIN`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/64819/2/0)

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Date])
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    t1.*,
    Days = DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.Date, ISNULL(t2.Date, GETDATE()))
FROM Cte t1
LEFT JOIN Cte t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
    AND t1.rn  = t2.rn - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example, You can do it without any joins.
Just use the Lead windowed function.

```
--Here is your data
DECLARE @Data TABLE(ID NVARCHAR(8),Date DATE)
INSERT INTO @Data(ID,Date)
VALUES
('ID1','09/01/2015'),
('ID1','09/04/2015'),
('ID2','09/04/2015'),   
('ID2','09/09/2015'), 
('ID2','09/15/2015'),
('ID3','09/09/2015'),
('ID4','09/15/2015')

--This is all you need, Assuming your using a version of SQL that supports LEAD!!!
SELECT  ID,DATEDIFF(D,Date,ISNULL(LEAD(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date),GETDATE()))
FROM        @Data
```

Comment: Can you check that on SQL Server 2008?

Comment: LEAD is not in 2008 R2, its in 2012 and above